# Azure functions output bindings parameter name does not included in context.bindings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

I use Iothub trigger functions , and I want to set Cosmosdb as output . When its done, I logged out context.bindings only shows {"IoTHubMessages":["Test Message"]}

[image]

[image]

[image]

did i miss something?

any suggestion would be appreciated, Thanks

EDITED :
functions.json
[image]

index.js

as third parameter, it is undefined.
[image]

Comment: maybe because your `message` is just a string and not a valid JSON document that could be stored in cosmosdb?

Comment: also, shouldnt it be `context.bindings.outputDocument`? Thats what you called the parameter name. Not `document`

Comment: Can you show your `function.json` file?

Comment: @silent, Thanks for reply, I didnt change 'message' because it did not change anything at all . just tried everything i could

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Thanks in advance , I've uploaded function.json, hope you can find something =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The output binding is not initialized before we create it by declaring it in index.js
2. If the comsumer group has reached the limit of connections , It would not proceed to receive data from Iothub input

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [official binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2?tabs=javascript#output).

#### If you want to store a single document during the Function execution

If your name your binding `outputDocument` in the `function.json` file, then you need to use `context.bindings.outputDocument = variable_containing_the_document;`.

#### If you want to store multiple documents during the Function execution

You need to use an Array. Create an Array, push any documents you want to save to it, and finally assign it to the `context.bindings.outputDocument`:

```
var documentsToSave = [];
documentsToSave.push(some_document_data);
documentsToSave.push(some_other_document_data);
//...
context.bindings.outputDocument = documentsToSave;
```

Comment: I thought the bindings would have the parameter name which I have defined in integrate output. Thank you

Comment: Your `function.json` is showing that the `name` for your output binding is `outputDocument`, so it should be on `context.bindings.outputDocument`